# Task owner pid in a Linux kernel module when executed in swapper

Tags: linux, module, kernel, task, pid

Given a task instance having pid 0 and comm "swapper/0", how to get the owner pid ?

==EDIT==

This happens using Netfilter hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `current` task in a netfilter outgoing hook context will always have a TGID (PID in the userspace) if the packet is UDP.

For a SYN TCP packets the `current` task will have a TGID, but a ACK packet will not have it.
To retrieve the TGID you have to calculate the socket sequence from the SYN packet using the packet length.

Answer (score 0):

> In the operating system Unix, every process except process 0 (the
>   swapper) is created when another process executes the fork() system
>   call. The process that invoked fork is the parent process and the
>   newly-created process is the child process. Every process (except
>   process 0) has one parent process, but can have many child processes.
>
> The operating system kernel identifies each process by its process
>   identifier. Process 0 is a special process that is created when the
>   system boots; after forking a child process (process 1), process 0
>   becomes the swapper process (sometimes also known as the "idle task").
>   Process 1, known as init, is the ancestor of every other process in
>   the system.

Comment: Ok thank you for that information. So how to find the process id that called this `fork()` system call ?

Comment: It explain a lot http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/c-process-control-functions/

Comment: I think I forgot an important information: I'm not the task owner. I mean that I'm just catching task_struct instances (using Netfilter hooks) and I have some of them having pid 0. I need to know the PID of the process that own the current task. Sorry.

Comment: I just realized that for UDP packets I always have the PID, it's only for TCP packets when having to transfer a bunch of packets (SYN, PSH and FIN packets have the PID but ACK not).